# Session post link read/notread

Tags: session, hyperlink

i have create a forum script for my website, all working ok but i m blocked on one think, i try to create a session for visited categoryes and posts, so if the post is not read by the user that is logged in, the script display an image "not_read.png" else the display "read.png"

So my code is like this:

```
$ctid = isset($_REQUEST['ctid']) ? $_REQUEST['ctid'] : '';
if ($action == 'spost'){
$select_posts = "SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE cat_id = '$ctid'....

session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();        
$_SESSION["CAT-$ctid"] = $ctid;
$ses_post = $_SESSION["CAT-$post_id"];
if ($ses_post == $post_id) {

echo "<img src='read.png'>";
}else{
echo "<img src='no_read.png'>";
}
}
```

is working but when user logout and login again all post show as not read.

Any idea how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Session is only alive during the lifetime of when you open a browser window and navigate to a site till either your code resets the session or the user closes the browser.

So storing your read/unread flag in session is unacceptable if you want it available to a user between different sessions.

Instead you should create a table and store it along with your forum posts that has an entry for the UserId, PostID which would have a row added every time a user viewed a post.  Then use this table to decide if it is read (there is a row in the table) or unread (no row matching the userid/postid)